# Тестирование базы данных

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, sql-server, тестирование

Вопрос по тестированию баз данных. Мой уровень квалицикации - начальный уровень. Ситуация:

Есть первичный источник данных от заказчика, назовем его "Источник_1".

Есть источник данных на тестовой среде, назовем его "Источник_2".

И есть загрузчик, который заливает данные из "Источник_1" в "Источник_2".

Мне нужно протестировать корректность работы этого загрузчика. То есть, нужно проверить, насколько данные в источнике на тестовой среде "Источник_2" соответствуют и сообразуются с данным в источнике от клиента "Источник_1".

Вопрос в том, каким образом выполнять проверку. Я пока вижу это так: читать документация с описанием схемы данных и свойствами полей и вручную сравнивать с этими требованиями каждую таблицу. Но качество проверки в этом случае будет низким.

Существуют ли какие-то способы выполнить проверку иначе, например, через запросы SQL?

Где можно найти исчерпывающую информацию по этому вопросу?

С чего начинать тестирование, как тестировать? Основные моменты при тестировании БД.

Comment: я бы предложил начать с точного описания терминов «соответствуют и сообразуются».

Comment: *Но качество проверки в этом случае будет низким* — нелохо бы расшифровать эту мысль.

Comment: про «соответствуют и сообразуются» не точно выразился - необходимо, чтобы схема БД, свойства полей в таблицах, расчетные значения в полях, и т.д. совпадали с истоником_1 от заказчика, т.е. чтобы схема БД и таблицы с данными на тестовой среде были полностью идентичны схеме БД и таблицам у заказчика

Comment: Про "Но качество проверки в этом случае будет низким" - имел ввиду, что при проверке вручную я просто буду смотреть на свойства полей в таблицах в БД и сравнивать их в требованиями в БД. Так я не смогу проверить схему БД, расчетные значения в таблицах. Может быть, получиться проверить связку таблиц в теории, но в работе не получиться. Т.е. нужно писать запросы, ли, как мне кажется. При все этом у меня нет общей картины, как вообще тестируется БД, какие этапы.

Comment: не понял, что подразумевается под «расчетными значениями в полях», но, судя по дальнейшему, вам требуется выяснить, не было ли изменений в схеме базы данных, не было ли изменений строк, не были ли добавлены/удалены строки, индексы, процедуры и т.п.. если так, то решение для *mysql* я привёл в ответе.

Comment: *как вообще тестируется БД* — здесь я пас. могу помочь лишь с практикой сравнения двух баз данных, которую и изложил в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### речь будет только о mysql

если необходимо лишь сравнить идентичность двух баз данных, то можно сделать их дампы (в наиболее подходящем виде) и сравнить эти дампы построчно. примерно так:

```
$ mysqldump --skip-opt --compact db1 > db1.dump
$ mysqldump --skip-opt --compact db2 > db2.dump
$ diff -ruaN db1.dump db2.dump
```

пример вывода команды `diff ...`:

```
--- db1.dump   2015-07-15 11:59:42.000000000 +0000
+++ db2.dump  2015-07-15 11:58:41.000000000 +0000
@@ -6,9 +6,4 @@
 /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
 INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (1);
 INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (2);
-/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
-/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
-CREATE TABLE `test2` (
-  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
-);
-/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
+INSERT INTO `test` VALUES (3);
```

из него видно, что есть два отличия:

1. отсутствие в `db2` таблицы `test2`
2. отсутствие в таблице `db1.test` строки со значением (в единственном тестовом столбце) `3`.

---

сравнивать данные (при отсутствии разницы в структуре) можно и по-таблично. вот [пример](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/compare-two-tables-to-find-unmatched-records-mysql.aspx).

в вашем случае таблицы будут находиться в разных базах данных, поэтому адресоваться надо, добавляя имя базы данных префиксом. примерно так:

```
> select ... from db1.table1 ... db2.table2 ...
```

---

ещё полезные (надеюсь) ссылки:
[Compare two MySQL databases, on command-line, with a free tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679399/compare-two-mysql-databases-on-command-line-with-a-free-tool)
[How do I see the differences between 2 MySQL dumps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840908/how-do-i-see-the-differences-between-2-mysql-dumps)

Comment: Пока не совсем понимаю, что это значит, т.к. уровень совсем начальный. Но попробую разобраться. Спасибо.

Comment: это как бы «дополнительная информация». а с чего можно начать, я предложил в комментариях к самому вопросу.

Comment: Уже кое что проясняется. Буду разбираться дальше. Спасибо!